# Google Spreadsheet function gets data from all sheets instead of just one

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

This is the function I have written, which sends an email to notify someone whenever a specified cell/row/column is edited, and I have it set to trigger onEdit.  It works as is.

```
/* This function send an email when a specified range is edited
 * The spreadsheets triggers must be set to onEdit for the function
*/

function sendNotification() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //Get Active cell
      var mycell = ss.getActiveSelection();
      var cellcol = mycell.getColumn();
      var cellrow = mycell.getRow();
  //Define Notification Details
      var recipients = "me@email.com";
      var subject = "Update to "+ss.getName();
      var body = ss.getName() + "has been updated.  Visit " + ss.getUrl() + " to view the changes.";
  //Check to see if column is A or B to trigger
      if (cellcol == 1, 2)
      {
  //check for row to trigger
        if (cellrow == 1)
        {
  //Send the Email
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
      }
  //End sendNotification
 }
}
```

My issue is that I need this to work only when a column or row on a certain sheet(page) of the spreadsheet is edited, rather than column X in any of the sheets within the spreadsheet.

Any ideas?  I'm hoping it's something simple that I missed, but I have been unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could interrupt the function after assigning the `sheet` variable:

```
if (sheet.getSheetName() != 'SheetIWant') return;
```

Comment: Worked great.  The other solution I found was this line of code.
if (event.source.getActiveSheet().getName()=="SheetIWant")

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the parameters that onEdit provides. It will tell you where the change happened.